# Return String[] From database

Tags: android, arraylist, autocompletetextview, arrays

I am trying to populate my AutoCompleteTextView from a column of values in my database.

The query I am running in my database is:

```
// GET MEMOS
    public ArrayList<String> autoCompleteMemo(String table)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        ArrayList<String> memoList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String SQL_GET_MEMOS = "SELECT memo FROM " + table;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL_GET_MEMOS, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                memoList.add(cursor.getString(0));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return memoList;
    }
```

And here is how I am attempting to set the values:

```
memoList = new String[db.autoCompleteMemo(table).size()];
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, memoList);
        etMemo.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For some reason, this does not appear to be working.  Am i converting from ArrayList to String[] properly?

Thanks

Also,

If i do something similar to this

```
String[] memoList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.memoList);
```

and populate that in Strings.xml it works fine.

Comment: Make sure you are actually getting data, try use cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName)); i remember having problem to get values from right column.  You can use array list instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my DB method to the following and it now works

```
public String[] autoCompleteMemo(String table) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String SQL_GET_MEMOS = "SELECT memo FROM " + table;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL_GET_MEMOS, null);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            int i = 0;

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                str[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("memo"));
                i++;
            }
            return str;
        }
        else {
            return new String[] {};
        }
    }
```